# How can another column's value includes value of primary key?

Tags: mysql

I want to include primary key's value to another column

ex)

[image]

but I don't know how can i do that.

Is there effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
UPDATE
  myTable
SET
  another_column = 
    CONCAT_WS("_", another_column, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 Select id, concat(cloumnname,"_",id) from tablename
```